# Install agp driver on my Fujitsu v6555 laptop using Ubuntu 11.10

Tags: 11.10, installation, drivers, graphics

My laptop came with Windows7 home basic operating system but I am interested for on Ubuntu.

I downloaded Ubuntu 11.10 and tried to install it using dual boot. I faced a problem with installing it, I solved it using f6 key.

After the installation it rebooted. While booting, I see that my screen is froze. Any ways, I hit my power button and started again using recovery mode. Whenever I use normal mode, I face this problem.

After a week I have learned that my laptop has two AGP card, one is a 12 MB and other 512 MB. 12 MB is installed normally but 512 MB AGP requires a driver. I downloaded this driver to my hard disk in .run format. So, please tell me how to install it?

AGP card model is: NVIDIA GeForce 8200M G

Anyone please help me.

Answer (score 1):

In Ubuntu the Nvidia card drivers are installed via the system.
In a terminal, type:

```
sudo jocket-gtk
```

enter your password and follow the instructions